# sed deletes all lines instead of the one line selected

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to remove one Line from `/etc/fstab` and use the `sed` command for that, but it removes everything within my file.

My `fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_backup /backup                 xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=30d58f5e-a432-4739-98f9-3f2ceb66fc03 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_wsbackup /wsbackup               xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=a59bad9c-8c89-4b20-aadd-e83c4ab22a6c swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
10.10.10.10 /mnt/wsbackup cifs user=user,password=password,domain=domain,vers=2.1 0 0
```

My script:

```bsh
MNTDIR="/mnt/wsbackup"
if grep -q "$MNTDIR" "/etc/fstab"
then
 sed -i -n "\:$MNTDIR:d" /etc/fstab
else
 ...
fi
```

If I use the command `sed "\:$MNTDIR:d" /etc/fstab` within my script the output I get looks like I want it to:

```
[root@labor-ssd ~]# sh check.sh
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_backup /backup                 xfs     defaults        0 0
#/dev/sdb /backup       ext4 defaults   0 0
UUID=30d58f5e-a432-4739-98f9-3f2ceb66fc03 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_wsbackup /wsbackup               xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=a59bad9c-8c89-4b20-aadd-e83c4ab22a6c swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
INFO: user mount configuration removed
```

But the changes are not written to the file so I use the `-i` option to write the changes to the file. The file is completely empty afterwards and I don't know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/etc/fstab` file becomes empty because you're not only using `-i` but also `-n`.

The `-n` option turns off the "default `p` (print) command" which is usually triggered at the end of each cycle.

With `-n`, your script truly outputs nothing, not even if you remove the `-i` option, because there is no `p` command in the script, not even the default `p` at the end of the cycle, which would have printed all lines that *weren't* deleted. Since the `sed` script outputs nothing, telling `sed` to do the changes in-place with `-i` empties the file.

So, to resolve your issue, remove `-n` from your command.

---

Personally, I would have written the code as

```bsh
mntdir=/mnt/wsbackup

cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.orig
sed "\\:$mntdir:d" /etc/fstab.orig >/etc/fstab
```

This allows us to keep a copy of the original `fstab` file.

Alternatively,

```bsh
mntdir=/mnt/wsbackup

sed -i.orig "\\:$mntdir:d" /etc/fstab
```

which would do pretty much the same thing, depending on what `sed` implementation you use.

Wrap that in a test on `grep -q -F -e "$mntdir" /etc/fstab` (similarly to what you did already) if you need to avoid doing anything to the file if the `$mntdir` string is not found in it, i.e.

```bsh
mntdir=/mnt/wsbackup

grep -q -F -e "$mntdir" /etc/fstab &&
sed -i.orig "\\:$mntdir:d" /etc/fstab
```

Comment: It is advisable to escape the `$mntdir` shell var prior to plugging it in the lhs of the s/// command, for those chars that are special in a `BRE` regex.

Comment: @RakeshSharma I ignored that since the variable's contents is something that is under full control of the script (it's a static string). If it was a string read from an external source, then it would have been more interesting to look at escaping special characters in the value of the variable.